# "Epic" badge Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, badges, daily-reputation-badges

I think that this badge should be a gold badge.

Don't you think it is quite impossible to earn?

Comment: So, what should Legendary be?

Comment: Yep, but I mean. Shouldn't it be Gold?

Comment: If Eoic were Gold, what would Legendary, which is currently Gold, be?

Comment: Yes, it's quite difficult to get. Is that a problem?! *Why* do you think it should be gold? Should there be a new silver badge?

Comment: ...hello? Do you have anything meaningful to add beyond *"Shouldn't it be Gold?"*?

Comment: ohh come on! It was only a question. Legendary have to be such as "Platinum"! a new typology of badge.

Comment: "It was only a question." but you felt the need to repeat it many times over anyway.

Comment: @BoltClock Do I smell burning [sock-puppets](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3667920/galma88?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=1)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have Epic. And Legendary.

> Don't you think it is quite impossible to earn?

Guess not...

Comment: No, it shouldn't. We already have a gold badge in that badge "family" - Legendary. Gold badges are supposed to be incredibly difficult to get. Silver ones are supposed to be hard to get.

Comment: @Galma88 and we repeat : WHY? If you want to change something, you need to explain why it would help or make sense..... so far the ONLY justification you have is "because"